# input data and run a php script from jquery event

Tags: php, jquery

I am having a problem getting data from jquery into a php script. I am trying to load a php script (i.e. send an email) with a variable (email address) from jquery event without leaving the original page and going to a confirmation page. Please help!

Here is my jquery code:

```
<script>
  $("#test").click(function() { 
    var id = 1;
    $("#target").load("javascript_test2.php", id);

  });
</script>
<div id="target">hmmm did it work?</div>
</body>
```

This is the php I would like to receive and process the code:

```
<div id="S1">
<?php 
$id = htmlspecialchars($_POST['id']);

for ($i=1; $i<=2; $i++) {
echo $id . 'Hello world ' . $i . '<br>'; 
}

require_once('lawyeralertemail.php');

?>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery ajax to post data into your PHP.
Here is a link:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

This will allow you to post data without reloading the page and give your user a better experience.

You can then use $_POST to capture the data inside your PHP.

Comment: Thanks! the site focuses on the jQuery side of the code, I can just use normal $id = htmlspecialchars($_POST['id']); on the php side? no other special code?

Comment: That is correct. Whatever you set your data to, you can capture through $_POST.